# What are the semantics of function as variable in C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

What are the semantics of declaring a function as a variable like this:

```
int main() {
    int foo();
    std::cout << foo; // prints 1
}
```

EDIT:
Why does this not cause a linker error?

Comment: how are you compiling that?

Comment: You are not declaring a function. Are you sure you're not getting confused with constructors?

Comment: This is not declaring a function as a variable. This is declaring a function, period.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That is a function declaration. Are you sure you're not getting confused with a sensible language? :-)

Comment: What you should be asking is "why does this not cause a linker error, when `foo` is never defined?". That question might even get some upvotes.

Comment: @molbdnilo omg you encouraged OP to change the question completely and the answers (even the accepted one) is quite off now

Comment: please dont change the question to ask for something different when there are already answers (even if the new question might be a "better" one)

Comment: @tobi303 Oops, I wasn't clear enough. (Again.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [this attempt to replicate your problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46cec2894a987727) you will see a warning message from the compiler:

> ```
> main.cpp:5:18: warning: the address of 'int foo()' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
> ```

A pointer to a function can *never* be a null pointer. ***But*** since all you have is a prototype, a declaration, and not any actual function definition the compiler evaluates it as "true".

Answer (score 2):

Compile your program in C++ [clang](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) compiler and see the warning:

```
Warning(s):
source_file.cpp:5:12: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    int foo();
           ^~
source_file.cpp:5:12: note: replace parentheses with an initializer to declare a variable
    int foo();
           ^~
            = 0
source_file.cpp:6:18: warning: address of function 'foo' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
    std::cout << foo; // prints 1
              ~~ ^~~
source_file.cpp:6:18: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    std::cout << foo; // prints 1
                 ^
                 &
2 warnings generated.
```

**Why output 1?**

Because according to warning **address of function 'foo' will always evaluate to 'true'**.